# Specify key pair for a Job Flow using AWS Java SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services

How do I specify a key pair using AWS Java SDK when creating a job flow? I need to specify the key pair so that I can later ssh into the master node.

I use the RunJobFlowRequest class but it does not have a way to specify the key pair. RunInstancesRequest class provides an api (setKeyName) for this, but I want to specifically create a Job Flow.

I know how to create a job flow using the console thereby specifying the key pair. But I'm looking to automate this so I would like to figure out how to do this with the Java SDK.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `setInstances` method on `RunJobFlowRequest`:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html

That method allows you to pass in a `JobFlowInstancesConfig` object:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/elasticmapreduce/model/JobFlowInstancesConfig.html

Inside that `JobFlowInstancesConfig` object, you can use the `setEc2KeyName` method to specify which EC2 Key Pair to enable when logging in as the `hadoop` user to the instances.